# edit Description and Due Due fields after adding to grid

Tags: tfs

I ran a query to display the outstanding bugs. I added the Description and Due Date column to the bug generated grid. I see the two new columns. I doubled clicked on a record, but don't see the Due Date and the Description fields in the form to edit. This is from 2012 Visual Studio.

How can I get these two fields on my form to edit?

Thanks

Comment: The Workitem list will allow you to select fields from all workitem types even if they aren't related to the Workitem types you are looking for.  I know in the default installation the Due Date Field is associated to the Task WorkItem Type

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, the WorkItem results will allow you to choose to display fields that don't belong to the WorkItem types you are looking for.  Due date for example is normally a field on the Task WorkItem type.  If you wanted to add the Description and Due Date fields to the Bug WorkItem type you'd need to modifiy the existing Bug WorkItem type to include those 2 fields.  If you don't have experiance editing workitem types I wouldn't recommend this because it can get pretty hairy.